# The specified table (SQL Server CE) does not exist in C#

Tags: c#, database, sqlcommand, sdf

I am using a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database file (`.sdf`) in C#. With the code I can read from `albums_tbl` but when I want to read from other tables while they exist, Visual Studio 2008 errors like this :

[image]

This is my code :

```
void FillAllitems()
{
     // 1
     // Open connection
     SqlCeConnection cnt = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = C:\com_honar\test1.sdf ");
     {
         cnt.Open();

         // 2
         // Create new DataAdapter
         using (SqlCeDataAdapter at = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM testi ", cnt))
         {
                    // 3
                    // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                    DataTable tt = new DataTable();
                    at.Fill(tt);
                    // 4
                    // Render data onto the screen
                    dataGridView2.DataSource = tt;
         }
    }
}
```

When I replace `albums_tbl` with `testi` it works just fine! But now errors for any other tables.

I have searched and found somebody had this problem too, but I did not uderstand what they did finally.

These are the tables :

[image]

Comment: I see that test1.sdf database is detached. That's maybe the reason.

Comment: Is this really the database file and not the one that will be copied to the bin directory *if there isn't one already*, or something?

Comment: If it were related to a detached database, the cnt.Open(); would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Since I dont know any other part of your code, I think, the connection can be handled a little bit better by enclosing it in a using block, so that it is closed automatically. I also have removed the extra space in the DataSource part. Like so:

```
void FillAllitems(){
    using (SqlCeConnection cnt = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\com_honar\test1.sdf")) {
        cnt.Open();                                                                            // Open connection
        using (SqlCeDataAdapter at = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM testi", cnt)){        // Create new DataAdapter
            DataTable tt = new DataTable();
            at.Fill(tt);                                                                   // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
            dataGridView2.DataSource = tt;                                                 // Render data onto the screen
        }
    }
}
```

I would also recommend the use of a command builder:

```
var sqCB = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
```

like so:

```
void FillAllitems(){
    using (SqlCeConnection cnt = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\com_honar\test1.sdf")) {
        cnt.Open();                                                                            // Open connection
        using (SqlCeDataAdapter at = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM testi", cnt)){        // Create new DataAdapter
            var sqCB = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(at);
            DataTable tt = new DataTable();
            at.Fill(tt);                                                                   // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
            dataGridView2.DataSource = tt;                                                 // Render data onto the screen
        }
    }
}
```